# Improve german vocabulary

Tags: english-to-german, online-resource

Can anyone suggest some great website to train German words? If anyone has some other great hint to learn german, I please you to poste the link below.

Comment: Have you tried Duolingo? Memrise & Babbel too.
Also, in this context you should be using "great" not grate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you read books that are apt for your level. Learning words is boring, tiresome and not efficient at all.